# Include PHP file with parameter

Tags: php

newbie in PHP here, sorry for troubling you.

I want to ask something, if I want to include a php page, can I use parameter to define the page which I'll be calling?

Let's say I have to include a title part in my template page. Every page has different title which will be represented as an image. So,

is it possible for me to call something `<?php @include('title.php',<image title>); ?>` inside my template.php?

so the include will return title page with specific image to represent the title.

thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An included page will see all the variables for the current scope.

```
$title = 'image title';
include('title.php');
```

Then in your title.php file that variable is there.

```
echo '<h1>'.$title.'</h1>';
```

It's recommended to check if the variable isset() before using it. Like this.

```
if(isset($title))
{
    echo '<h1>'.$title.'</h1>';
}
else
{
    // handle an error
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, if you want to use a function call approach. It's best to make the function specific to activity being performed by the included file.

```
function do_title($title)
{
     include('title.php');  // note: $title will be a local variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can create a function to include the file and pass a variable.

```
function includeFile($file, $param) {
    echo $param;
    include_once($file);
}

includeFile('title.php', "title");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your included file, you could do this:

```
<?php
return function($title) {
    do_title_things($title);
    do_other_things();
};

function do_title_things($title) {
    // ...
}

function do_other_things() {
    // ...
}
```

Then, you could pass the parameter as such:

```
$callback = include('myfile.php');
$callback('new title');
```

Another more commonly used pattern is to make a new scope for variables to be passed in:

```
function include_with_vars($file, $params) {
    extract($params);
    include($file);
}

include_with_vars('myfile.php', array(
    'title' => 'my title'
));
```

Comment: include(..) for a missing file is not a failure, but a warning and will return False. Therefore, $callback = include(..) is an unsafe practice.

Answer (score 0):

The included page will already have access to those variables defined prior to the include. If you require include specific variables, I suggest defining those variables on the page to be included